# sqlcmd.exe is hanging after running sql statement in inno package

Tags: inno-setup, sqlcmd

I'm write installation package using inno for ms sql script. I have the following code:

```
  strParam := '-U hel -P password -S ServerName -d test -Q "sp_test"';
  try
     Exec('sqlcmd.exe', strParam, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
     result := ResultCode = 0;
  except
     Exec('osql.exe', strParam, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
     result := ResultCode = 0;
  end;
```

Sp executes ok but black screen with sqlcmd.exe is hanging until either I type exit or close it. I want a window with sqlcmd.exe closed after sp is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to use sqlcmd first, and then using osql as a backup if that `Exec` throws. The documentation suggests to me that this won't work at all; you need `if not Exec('sqlcmd', ...) then` instead,

That aside, we use osql exclusively for our sql updates, and have never had issues with it not terminating. If you don't have a good reason for investing in two separate sql update programs, just use the one that works better. If that happens to be osql, so be it.

Comment: As it turns out, the problem was with the computer memory. When I closes several running applications, code started to work properly. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today.  My answer was that I have many differing versions of SQL command and the SQL program files.  I took one path statement out for an older version and it started working